# assets not updating on Rails 5 that are placed in the public directory like .js and .css on Development Enviroment

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have made a CMS with rails, users can upload js and css freely to customize the pages made by the CMS, I just generate a simple link to the assets according to what they are, and they have worked without any problems, how ever after updating the service to Rails5, there have been some troubles with the files uploaded in the public directory.

Mainly when people directly edit the css file in the public directory since they prefer to do that when running the CMS locally with there preferred editors when doing initial mocking.

The things known are,

1. The css or js does not update when locally edited (so changing body background to #000 or something doesn't show up)
2. directly accessing them in the browser seems to update them for subsequent accesses
3. assets are mostly generated by compass or webpack-dev-server since js is jsx and css is sass, but the problem reproduces even when directly editing css or js.

I know its a vague problem to ask, but I feel the asset pipeline may be interfering with files directly placed in the public directory somehow, its even more bizarre since it happens on some computers, and not on all of them.

Comment: The asset pipeline doesn't handle anything from the public folder. I wonder if you have a `config.static_cache_control` set with a high max-age. You could inspect the request with chrome's developer tools/network and see if those assets are being pulled from the server or they're being served by the local browser cache.

Comment: Yup sure enough they are taking it from disk or memory cache. This might be the break through I needed. much thanks. will come back if I succeed in disabling it.